# Populating drop down select menu from rows in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, loops

I am developing a website wherein users are able to add friends. Here, I'm using a simple `SELECT` statement to show which users are currently *pending* to be a friend. Here's what I have so far:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
<tr>
    <td><img src="<?=$photo;?>" /></td>
    <td><?=$realname;?></td>
    <td><?=$userid;?></td>
    <td><?=$username;?></td>
    <td>
        <select name="action">
            <option value="skip">Skip (no action)</option>
            <option value="accept">Accept</option>
            <option value="deny">Deny</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?=$userid;?>" />
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Now, I'm not so sure about the `select` part. It's easy to process if I will only select options for one user but how should I go about it so that when I select different options for two different users, I'd still be able to separate the results? Because right now, what it's giving me is `uid=1&action=accept&uid=2&action=deny`. I'm thinking of changing the select name from `action` to `action[]` but I may be wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It will be better if you will show the query to mysql itself.

Comment: I didn't think it would matter. It's a simple `SELECT * FROM users WHERE pending=1` statment and I just used `extract` to make them variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the uid as the key for your action.  For example:

```
<select name="action[<?php echo $userid; ?>]">
    <option value="skip">Skip (no action)</option>
    <option value="accept">Accept</option>
    <option value="deny">Deny</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How should I process it then upon receiving? Strip "action"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  You wouldn't need to strip anything.  You can simply run a `foreach ($_GET['action'] as $userId => $action)`

Comment: I get it now. I thought the `[` was a typo. It's missing the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

use checkboxes instead of selects.
and pass userid as checkbox name

```
<td><checkbox name="skip[] value="<?=$userid?>"></td> 
<td><checkbox name="accept[] value="<?=$userid?>"></td> 
<td><checkbox name="deny[] value="<?=$userid?>"></td>
```

so, on the server side you will have 3 arrays with user ids:
`$_POST['skip']` with to be skipped ids and so on

Comment: I'm guessing radio buttons would be more apt for this case since you should only be able to perform one of the three actions.

Comment: yeah, it seems radio even better.